# substract dates and concatenate strings - spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am really new in datascience... actually doing a course.

I am trying to create a query with spark sql... could you help me with the mistakes? thank you so much in advance
f.e. I dont know how to concatenate strings and also substract dates.
Here is the query Im trying to make it work:

```
sqlDF5 = sqlContext.sql(sqlQuery=

"select document_number, count((distinct document_number) ||'-'|| rloc) as frecuency, 

sum(revenue_amount_seg) as money, 

datediff(day, max(departure_date_leg) as datetime,'2014-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime) as recency, 

from clientes_unicos group by document_number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I could find the solution, if anyone ever needs it:

sqlDF = sqlContext.sql(sqlQuery="select document_number,\

count(distinct(concat(document_number, ',', rloc))) as frecuency, \

sum(revenue_amount_seg) as money, \

datediff(to_date('2014-01-01 00:00:00'), to_date(max(departure_date_leg))) as recency \

from clientes_unicos group by document_number")